# Will Santa Claus ever respawn?

Tags: terraria

You get Santa Claus after defeating the Frost Legion.  Can you get him if he dies AFTER the holidays, and will he available the NEXT holiday?

Answer (score 4):

He's available every year during the holiday season (defined as December 15th - December 31st). Outside of this time frame, he dies the instant he spawns.

If you've already defeated the Frost Legion, he *will* respawn at the end of next year, provided you've defeated the Frost Legion on that world.

Comment: Just confirming that he is available again this year.

Answer (score -1):

If you also change the date on your system he will respawn because your system thinks its the time of year he should be there.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Arqade. This seems like a comment to an existing post/answer. You will be able to comment on posts once you have enough reputation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/167412)

Comment: @Samyam, are you interpreting this as no answer, or a poor / incorrect answer? **Question**: can you spawn santa after the holidays? **OPs Answer**: If you change the date on your system, he should spawn, because your system thinks it is the right time for him to spawn; I wouldnt say this is a good quality answer, but it is definetly an answer, and [a close vote is not a super down vote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Comment: @Timelord64 this itself doesn't answer the question. What date should I change to? The other answer answers it. This answer should be edited to include the other answer (this will be a good but dupe answer) or be an edit/comment to the other answer (you said that it shouldn't be).